# How to prevent the second "gem install XXX" from reinstalling?

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

`gem install XXX` seems to run the installation process even if the package is already installed.  i.e. if I do

```
$ gem install chef
...
$ gem list | grep chef
chef (0.9.8)
$ gem install chef
...
```

the second `gem install chef` seems to install `chef` again!

How can I get this to result in a noop and the message "chef is already installed", or similar, the way most package management tools work?

I can achieve what I want via

```
$ gem list | grep chef > /dev/null || gem install chef
```

but there must be a better way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `/lib/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb` file of the RubyGems sources, there is no other, "legal", way to do that, so your own is the best.